WinForms Toolbox controls greyed out
Situation:
I use Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.9.6,
I installed it on a new computer and imported a WinForms project from my old computer.
My Problem:
Now all Toolbox Items are greyed out. I can still duplicate existing labels etc. by copypasting.
What I tried:

Resetting Toolbox
Deleting .tbd files
Repairing VS
Creating a new project as WinForms (.NET Framework) and importing all files to it.

I restarted VS after every step
What am I doing wrong?

SOLUTION: Typed in "dotnet restore" into the NuGet console and restarted VS and it works.
